# Convert a 2x2 GridLayout containing ImageViews into a 4 slice pie

Tags: android, android-layout, grouping, android-gridlayout

I have a circular button with four images in a 2x2 grid using `GridLayout`. So now the button shows up as a circle behind the image grid.

Most of the solutions I saw online are to make the entire image a circle. I need to instead convert mine to a pie with four slices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_1"
        android:padding="1.5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_2"
        android:padding="1.5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_3"
        android:padding="1.5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_4"
        android:padding="1.5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

I have a custom button that I inflate this layout with.

Help!